# Simple PrintToFile program

Tags: java, file-io

I'm trying to write a simple java program in Eclipse that prints these four lines into a file "hello.txt". THe problem is, that nothing is happening, it doesn't create a new file, and if i make a file called "hello.txt" the program doesn't overwrite it. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your answers. :)

```
import java.io.*;

public class output {
    {
        try{
            PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new File("hello.txt"));
            output.println("Hello World!");
            output.println("this is ");
            output.println("four lines of");
            output.println("text.");
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("Cannot write file!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just run your code on windows putting it in main method and it works (it creates the file). try with an absolute path, perhaps you are checking the wrong directory.
You also should call

```
output.close();
```

Comment: I'm running at Ubuntu 11.10. I added the output.close(); and a main, and it still doesn't work. I can't use an absolut path, cause i have to be able to share the program with 2 other guys that is using Mac and Windows.

Comment: I should add, that I havn't had any problems with programming Java in Ubuntu this far at all so this shouldn't be an issue?

Comment: try only for testing purposes to use an absolute path. You can achieve the same result using these lines of code           File file =new File("hello.txt"); System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());PrintStream output = new PrintStream(file);

Comment: Ok! Now that I use the absolute path i get the text printet to a file! (even without the use of output.close();)   Very nice! But if I do not use an absolute path it doesn't create the file. I can't see the file either in eclipse or in my folder.

Comment: Ok, I got it now! You have to drag the file into your Eclipse folder and check the button "Link to file". Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems here:

1. you need to close your output stream when you're done with `output.close();`
2. Your class needs a main method  `void main(String[] args` that calls the output routine
3. The output routine needs to be enclosed in a method

Comment: Is step 2 and 3 necessary for the program to work? I've added an output.close(); and a main method void main(String[] args, but the program still doesn't work.

Comment: #2 is needed as the JVM will call main when you try to execute the program (if you don't have a main method, nothing will happen). If you put the output code right in the body of the main method, you don't need #3.

Answer (score 1):

```
output.close();
```

or

```
output.flush();
```

If you don't close your streams, they won't be saved to disk.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do it is like this

```
import java.io.*;
class PrintStreamDemo {  
    public static void main(String args[]){ 
        FileOutputStream out; 
        PrintStream ps; // declare a print stream object

        try {
            // Create a new file output stream
            out = new FileOutputStream("myfile.txt");

            // Connect print stream to the output stream
            ps = new PrintStream(out);

            ps.println ("This data is written to a file:");
            System.err.println ("Write successfully");

            ps.close();
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println ("Error in writing to file");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add `output.close();`

```
try{
            PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new File("hello.txt"));
            output.println("Hello World!");
            output.println("this is ");
            output.println("four lines of");
            output.println("text.");
            output.close();
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("Cannot write file!");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to create your file if it is not there. With that you create the PrintStream-Object and write the content you like in it. Finally don't forget to flush and close the stream.

```
 try{
 File f = new File("C:/hello.txt");
 if (!f.exists()){
    f.createNewFile();
 }
 PrintStream output = new PrintStream(f);
 output.println("Hello World!");
 output.println("this is ");
 output.println("four lines of");
 output.println("text.");
 output.flush();
 output.close();
}catch(FileNotFoundException e){
  System.out.println("Fil kan ikke skrives!");
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to write `output.close();`